# Nextprime program working fine for almost all values but glitching at 83, 84, 89 to 92 (so far)

Tags: python, numbers, primes

```
n = int(input('Enter a value : '))

for p in range(n,n+999):
    p = n+1
    if p > n:
        for i in range(2,p):
            if p % i == 0:
                p = p+1
        else:
            print('The prime number after', n, 'is', p)
            break
```

#output for 89:Enter a value : 89
The prime number after 89 is 95

Comment: When would `p` ever not be `> n`? You are setting `p = n+1`? Also, you set the variable `p` for `range(n,n+999)` then immediately reset the value for `p` to be equal to `n+1`?

Comment: It's incorrect to increment `p` within `for i in range(2,p)`. If some checks passed for smalelr `p`, you still have to re-check again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and carefully check through the logic of the program. For example, try putting `print(p, i)` before `if p % i == 0:`, and see what combinations actually get tested. Do those make sense to you? Why or why not? The issue here doesn't appear to be with writing the code, per se, but with understanding the actual logical steps that the code has to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting tripped up in the initial starting point of the test range as well as breaking out of both of the for loops when a prime number is found.  With that I offer up the following code snippet.

```
n = int(input('Enter a value : '))

for p in range(n + 1,n+99):     # Set the starting point for p here instead of including "p = n + 1 statement
    found = False               # Use this to break out of the for loop when a prime number is found
    for i in range(2,p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break               # The number being tested is not a prime number
        else:
            print('The next prime number after', n, 'is', p)
            found = True        # Gets us out of the for loop
            break
    if found == True:
        break
```

The bits I revised was initiating the range starting value for "p" immediately in the for loop.  Otherwise, the value of "p" was continually being reset to "n + 1".  The other bit was adding in a Boolean work variable to be used to break out of the initial for loop when a prime number was found.

Testing this out with an entry value netted the next prime number of "91".

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Prime$ python3 Prime.py
Enter a value : 89
The next prime number after 89 is 91
```

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your code.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input('Enter a value : '))

for p in range(n+1, n+99):
    for i in range(2,p):
        if p % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print('The prime number after', n, 'is', p)
        break
```

Took your suggestions, tweaked the code a bit, working fine now. You're right, Mr. Knetchel. Thanks, NoDakker for pointing at resetting the 'p' value to 'n+1'.